# Set Popping (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, set, hashtable, python-internals

Lets say you have a set:

```
foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

In the book I am currently reading, Pro Python, it says that using `foo.pop()`will pop an arbitrary number from that selection. BUT...When I try it out, it `pops 1, then 2, then 3...`Does it do it arbitrarily, or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: This has to do with the hash function that a set uses to map it's contents to locations in the memory. Try doing `hash()` on different data types and see what numbers you get. The arbritrary number popped out of a set _will_ be the _next_ element in the set. It just so happens that the "order" the set stores the data may not _necessarily_ be ordered as far as you are concerned. In this example, the order the elements are in happen to coincide with the order that the hashmap is stored/retrieved.

Comment: I found the same thing today and I want to up your question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason it says it is arbitrary is because there is no *guarantee* about the ordering it will pop out. Since you just created the set, it may be storing the elements in a "nice" order, and thus `.pop()` happens to return them in that order, but if you were to mutate the set, that might not continue to hold.

Example:

```
>>> foo = set()
>>> foo.add(-3)
>>> foo.add(-1)
>>> foo.add(2)
>>> foo.pop()
2
>>> foo.pop()
-3
```

Answer (score 15):

Set and dictionaries are implemented using hash tables.  They are unordered collections, meaning that they have no guaranteed order.

The order you're seeing is a non-guaranteed implementation detail.  In CPython, the hash value for an integer is the integer itself:

```
>>> [hash(i) for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

That implementation detail causes the integers to appear ordered in your set.  Other sets would be semi-ordered, `{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` appears as `set([8, 9, 5, 6, 7])`.

In contrast, other datatypes such as *str* have different hash functions and will  appear to be more scrambled.  For example:

```
# Example of scrambling str objects in a 64-bit build
>>> {'red', 'green', 'blue'}
set(['blue', 'green', 'red'])
```

The *set.pop* method pops off entries left-to-right.  That is also a non-guaranteed implementation detail.

**The short answer to your question is Yes, the ordering is arbitrary but No, what you saw wasn't just a coincidence either, rather it was an interesting non-guaranteed implementation detail.**

Hope this clears-up the mystery for you :-)